# probability of drawing three hearts union/intersecting drawing at most 1 king

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have a question that is asking the probability of the intersection and union of two cases. The question assumes you are drawing 5 cards from a deck of 52.

**A**: Drawing at least 3 hearts
**B**: Drawing at most 1 King

I have solved the two as
$P(A)\frac{\binom{13}{4}\binom{39}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}}+\frac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}+\frac{\binom{13}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}=9.28\%$  and
$P(B)\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}+\frac{\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}=95.83\%$

So now I cannot quite figure out how to $P(A\cap B)$ and $P(A\cup B)$. For $P(A\cap B)$ I am not sure what $P(B|A)$ would be. I know there are two cases:

1. Three hearts and NO kings
2. Three hearts and ONE king

If anyone can provide some pointers it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Actually you have made a great start in calculating $P(A), P(B)$. In the process, you have actually partitioned $A$ into $3$ events as $3, 4, 5$ hearts and $B$ into $2$ events as $0, 1$ kings. So when consider the intersection $A \cap B$, you naturally have $3 \times 2 = 6$ partitions to be considered, and you have named the first $2$. When you are counting, I recommend you to partition the deck into $4$ groups, namely the heart king, the remaining $12$ hearts, the remaining $3$ kings, and the remaining $52 - 1 - 12 - 3 = 36$ cards. For the union, you just apply inclusion-exclusion principle.